# Restore Send icon in Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app

I have lost the "send" icon on my Apple mail, top right corner
How do I restore it?

Answer (score 1):

Start a new message  <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> / <kbd>n</kbd>   , then with that message front-most [this gives different choices than if the main window is at the front]

View menu > Customise Toolbar...
Drag the default set at the bottom into the toolbar, or just drag the Send icon back to where you'd like it.